# In React, how do I update a text form field in which the backing state is an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, components

I'm creating a React 16.13.0 application and trying to design a form that submits to an endpoint that accepts data like so ...

```
{
        "name": "Test 8899",
        "types": [
            {"name": "Library"}
        ],
        "address": {
            "formatted": "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212",
            "locality": {
                "name": "Chicago",
                "postal_code": "60654",
                "state": 19313
            }
        },
        ...
```

Notice the "types" input is an array of items.  So I have created a FormContainer component with the state as follows ...

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484
  static REACT_APP_PROXY = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      provinces: [],
      errors: [],
      newCoop: {
        name: '',
        types: [{
          name: ''
        }],
```

and then a "handleTypeChange" function for the type component itself ...

```
  handleTypeChange(e) {
    let self=this
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    //update State
    this.setState({newCoop: types[0].name = value}); 
  }

...
            <Input inputType={'text'}
               title= {'Type'} 
               name= {'types[0].name'}
               value={this.state.newCoop.types[0].name} 
               placeholder = {'Enter cooperative type'}
               handleChange = {this.handleTypeChange}

               /> {/* Type of the cooperative */}
```

However, when I start typing in the field, I immediately get an error

```
Line 96:29:  'types' is not defined  no-undef
```

What's the proper way to set up my handle input change function so that I can properly record the user input in my state?

Comment: can `types` array have multiple objects or only 1 object?

Comment: It would have helped if you pointed us to the code at `Line 96:29`. Mean while, could you kindly "unstring" this `name= {'types[0].name'}`? This should typically evaluate to some value. Also because of the complexity of your data, you might want to use a `spread` operator.

Comment: do you really need to pass the value prop? the input should display the text without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: the handleTypeChange method would not have access to the class component (this) when you pass it as a prop.

Two ways to do deal with "this" when passing a class method as a prop in a class component:

Bind "this" to the method (handleTypeChange) in the constructor function

```
constructor (props) {
  super();
  ...
  this.handleTypeChange = this.handleTypeChange.bind(this);
}
```

or pass an arrow function to handleChange prop, like this:

```
handleChange = {(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

to merge the state inside `handleTypeChange`, you would do this

```
  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      // merge the rest of the state, then spread the love here
      newCoop: { ...this.state.newCoop, types: [{ name: e.target.value }] }
    });
  }
```

take a look at my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hawking-eikrt?file=/src/Comp.js:247-436) for a more complete example.